# Why doesn't :active or :focus work on text links in webkit? (safari & chrome)

Tags: webkit

I think I'm overlooking something, call it a long day, but why isn't this working? The styles found in the "li a:active, li a:focus" persist in Firefox and IE but not webkit. Does webkit only support the `:focus` pseudo class on form elements?

```
    #footer ul li a {
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 font-size: 95%;
 padding: 15px 15px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
    }

    #footer ul li a:hover {
 color: #f00;
    }

    #footer ul li a:active, #footer ul li a:focus {
 border-top: 1px #f00 solid;
 color: #f00;
 padding-top: 14px;
    }

    #footer ul li a:focus:hover {
 cursor: default;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The `:focus` pseudo class is meant for form elements, so the Webkit implementation does not apply it to other elements unless a tabindex attribute is added to the tag.
http://nemisj.com/focusable/

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the anchor element not being mouse-focusable is a long-standing bug, see https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26856 for the reference.