# OnFocus for Google Chrome Browser

Tags: html, css

Please visit this page:
http://hyindia.com/demo/agenda/index.html

On Top Menu, You can see the Buttons/Links and they have hover and focus/onclick effect(CSS), But focus/onclick effect is only working in Mozilla Firefox Browser, I want this to work in Google Chrome, Opera and Safari Browser also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using the onclick() event instead of the onfocus().

I vaguely recall this issue occurring in Chrome, not recently but still the same issue. I will attempt to find a link on the details, but in the mean time, try using the onclick() event instead and see if that solves your issue.

**EDIT:** I noticed that in Chrome you can see the onfocus() work when tabbing into the element...

I did find a few examples / links you could take a look at to help.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=62fbd469dcbe910c&hl=en

- Discusses the issue Chrome has / had with onFocus() in the past. Also a solution on using onclick() as I suggested before, in place of the onFocus()

[problem with Chrome form handling: input onfocus="this.select()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939122/problem-with-chrome-form-handling-input-onfocus-this-select)

- Past question from here that also explains how to bind the action into the onClick() to allow onFocus() to successfully work in Chrome.

> The way I got around this was by creating a wrapper function that uses setTimeout() to >delay the actual call to select(). Then I just call that function in the focus event of >the textbox. Using setTimeout defers the execution until the call stack is empty again, >which would be when the browser has finished processing all the events that happened when >you clicked (mousedown, mouseup, click, focus, etc). It's a bit of a hack, but it works.

```
function selectTextboxContent(textbox)
{
setTimeout(function() { textbox.select(); }, 10);
}
```

Then you can do something like this to do the selection on focus:

```
<input onfocus="selectTextboxContent(this);" type="text" value="Search">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a tabindex to your links ;) I did some tests and it worked.  More info on: http://nemisj.com/focusable/

Suggested by Kirk Woll in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169855/why-doesnt-active-or-focus-work-on-text-links-in-webkit-safari-chrome)

See ya' :)